# How do I choose a laptop if I'm interested in learning and applying data science?

Tags: hardware

I just got started with learning data science, and I was wondering what type of laptop I'd need to buy. I understand that this might come probably a little too early -- but my current laptop absolutely needs to be replaced and I don't want to buy a new laptop only to find out about a year later that I can't apply what I've learnt.

So, what are the minimum specs I should be looking out for? I've read about Amazon's AWS that allows us to create and access virtual machines using the cloud -- is that a good idea, especially considering that I'm only starting out?

I won't be using a laptop for any other intensive activities such as gaming or video-editing. Should I get a high-end laptop or stick to a basic model and just use cloud based services for my data science needs? If the latter (buying a basic model) is a better choice, does that also need certain basic hardware requirements?

Comment: Try to buy a desktop with a good graphics card, something like 1080 ti or if you can afford, try to buy Tesla. Moreover, try to buy a motherboard which supports at least 32GB RAM, and try to use all of them. Laptops are not good for learning tasks specifically if you have deep learning tasks. They may get really hot which is not good for health :)

Comment: Yep go with a desktop in a long run with a lower end lapi to SSH..

Comment: I work as a data scientist. Generally, a laptop type doesn’t make a difference in data science. Try learning statistics first. Statistics doesn’t require a high end graphics card. Understand basic concepts of mathematical statistics first before you jump into overkill algorithms.

Comment: Try investigating beforehand what Linux distributions run on that type of laptop, there are lots  that do not support any distro. Also, whatch out for the pitfalls of UEFI  and SSD in regards to installation of bootloaders for different OS. Lastly, see to it that you can import and export data at a decent rate - Gigabit ethernet, good USB 3.0 (tested)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit *off-topic* and *very subjective*. It is subjective as it depends on what you want to achieve. I am answering because I have been in this journey for the last 2 years and I can confidently comment

> **You certainly DO NOT need a high-performing laptop to start off with data science/machine learning.**

based on the following reasons (at least not for the first year or two):

- Building the foundations of machine learning, statistics and programming takes longer time that you may think (your objective is solely learning), till you get to do heavy deep learning optimization on images etc.
- Even if you get to heavy tasks earlier, there is increasing availability of free clouds like Kaggle, Google Colab etc. that you can run heavy jobs. Yes, runtime on those clouds are at present limited (e.g. as of now it is 1-hr GPU computing at Kaggle), but this will change really soon.

Thus, you are good with a laptop with 1TB hard-disk, 16GB RAM and Core i7, surely depending on your budget lower specification like mine (MacBook Pro 256GB, 8GB RAM, Core i5) also works just fine, unless you have more money to spare.

P.S.: I admit not being able to work on some image-based ML competitions in Kaggle due to limited computing power, but that time (~ a year ago) free clouds were less available.

By the way, Welcome Onboard!

Comment: 4 gigs is outdated now, 8 gigs is the bare minimum...

Comment: I meant 8GB, mine is not 4GB! Thanks for the catch. ;-)